# Visual studio cant debug when running in administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, administrator

Whenever I run VS as Administrator (on Windows 7) pressing play, hitting F5 or selecting start debugging from the drop-down all do nothing. No error message, just nothing.

The project builds ok, runs ok when you run VS as non-admin, and also works if run in release mode on admin or non-admin.

Is this a visual studio / windows 7 thing?

Edit; VS 2010 Ultimate, Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Comment: Could you please specify the Visual Studio version you are using? That may be relevant to finding a answer.

Comment: good point, edited above

Answer (score 1):

Try following the solution in this guide http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2011/04/visual-studio-2010-wont-debug-under.html

I have been able to run Visual Studio 2010 in administrator mode while debugging, so it is not a Visual Studio 2010 / Windows 7 problem.